# Finding out if any time zone is in midnight currently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on scheduler module, for which I want to know if any X time zone is in midnight currently. Is there any library/gem for this purpose? If not, what would be a good logic to find out?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you will hit the moment of midnight when you check that. It is very impractical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your phrasing is a little ambiguous ("any X time zone"), so I'll address another possible interpretation:

If you'd like to check whether "it's midnight somewhere", with "midnight" understood broadly to mean any time from 00:00 to 00:59, a simple one-liner is

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.any?{ |time| time.now.hour.zero? }
```

To check that it's precisely 00:00 (or 00:00:00, although I can't imagine why you would want to do that...), add the appropriate conditions to the boolean block:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.any?{ |time| time.now.hour.zero? && time.now.min.zero? }
```

You can probably leave off the `ActiveSupport::` when calling `TimeZone.all` from within your Rails app.

[[source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-all)]

Comment: I needed to know _which_ timezones were midnight, so I used `select`: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |time| time.now.hour.zero? }`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
> Time.zone 
=> (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
> given_time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
> Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(given_time_zone)
=> Sun, 23 Mar 2014 23:55:57 CDT -05:00
```

Then you could check if the `hour` is `zero` to check if it's within 12 midnight till 1AM:

```
> Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(given_time_zone).hour == 0
=> false
```